# Converting a MPAndroidChart view to a Bitmap gives ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, bitmap, mpandroidchart

I am trying to convert a [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) LineChart view to a Bitmap object when the user taps on a button, to save the chart as an image. However, I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. I am using MPAndroidChart v. 3.0.0-beta. The code is the following:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View graph) {
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(graph.getWidth(), graph.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable = graph.getBackground();

    if (bgDrawable != null)
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    view.draw(canvas);

    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

The exception is the following and line 1409 of ConstantsAndUtils.java is *view.draw(canvas)* above.

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
>        at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.LineChartRenderer.drawCircles(LineChartRenderer.java:689)
>        at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.LineChartRenderer.drawExtras(LineChartRenderer.java:595)
>        at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarLineChartBase.onDraw(BarLineChartBase.java:252)
>        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14788)
>        at com.dnaphone.edu.utils.ConstantsAndUtils.getBitmapFromView(ConstantsAndUtils.java:1409)
>        at com.dnaphone.edu.fragments.HistoryExperimentResultFragment$24.doInBackground(HistoryExperimentResultFragment.java:1886)
>        at com.dnaphone.edu.fragments.HistoryExperimentResultFragment$24.doInBackground(HistoryExperimentResultFragment.java:1655)
>        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

**Edit: the issue has been solved in the final 3.0.0 release.**

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save chart as image, then you should use

`mChart.saveToGallery("test.png", 50);`

in this `test.png` is your image name and `50` quality of your image and this image saved in your device storage.

Comment: I think there is nothing on this that generate ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: I have checked the library code on GitHub and there is an error in a function that updates a counter up to the size of an array, then use it to acces such an array. Of course, if the counter has value n, the last array element has index n-1. This generates the exception. I am waiting for the author of the lib to fix the problem.